# No test cases are showing in the NUnit test explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I have installed the NUnit VS extension into VS Community 2015. I have a VS solution containing a test project and within that I have a class

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void canAddOnePlusOne()
    {
        Assert.Fail("Can't add");
    }
}
```

The solution (re)builds successfully. Nothing appears in the Test Explorer. There is no output from running all tests. How do I get my tests to appear in the Test Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Without version numbers Install-Package NUnit had installed test framework version 3. The extension (without version #s) supports up to 2.6.4 version. Had to install the NUnit3 extension.